# Vuetify data-table combine dynamic slots with row/item slots

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a reusable vuetify datatable. I want the ability to pass dynamic slots or item slots if I want to and both should work. This is the code

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :dense="dense"
    :hide-default-header="hideDefaultHeader"
    :loading="loading"
    :options.sync="settings"
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    :server-items-length="itemLength"
    @click:row="handleClick"
    :height="height"
>
    <-- 1st part-->
    <template v-for="field in slots" v-slot:[field.field]="{ item }">
        <slot :name="field.field" :item="item"></slot>
    </template>
    <-- 2nd part -->
    <template v-slot:item="{item}">
        <slot name="item" v-bind="item"></slot>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

this is then makes a component called `DataTable` which I then use like this

```
<DataTable
    v-if="tabs == n"
    :items="items"
    :loading="loading"
    :headers="headers"
    :options="serverOptions"
    :slots="slots"
    :total="toatl"
    @updateOptions="updateOptions($event, n)"
>
```

I also have a slot array like this

```
slots: [{ field: "item.CREATOR" }, { field: "item.BODY" }]
```

I want the ability to either use the `item` slot using the `2nd part` or use a specific column slot defined in the slot array `1st part`. Right now the dynamic slots unless i comment out the `2nd part`. This is how i currently slot each part

1st part:

```
<template v-slot:item.CREATOR="{ item }">
    <strong>{{item.FIRSTNAME}} {{item.LASTNAME}}</strong>
</template>
```

2nd part:

```
<template v-slot:item="item">
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.MESSAGESTATUS}}</td>
        <td>sdsd</td>
        <td>sfsf</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are trying to do may be easly solved using computed properties for the dynamic slots you wish:

```js
 computed: {
   creatorSlots: function () {
    //Filters the slots of type CREATOR
    return this.slots.filter(slot => slot.field==='CREATOR');
   }
 }
```

so now you can use your First Part for every 'CREATOR' slot on your slots array:

```js
<template v-for="(slot,i) in creatorSlots" v-slot:[`item.${slot.field}`]="{ item }">
    <strong :key="i">{{item.FIRSTNAME}} {{item.LASTNAME}}</strong>
</template>
```

If you have other slots that need to be processed in another way you only need to use another computed property for your other slots and repeat the process...

```js
 computed: {
   bodySlots: function () {
    //Filters the slots of type BODY
    return this.slots.filter(slot => slot.field==='BODY');
   }
 }
```

```js
<template v-for="(slot,i) in bodySlots" v-slot:[`item.${slot.field}`]="{ item }">
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.MESSAGESTATUS}}</td>
        <td>sdsd</td>
        <td>sfsf</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Hope it helps, I came to here with a similar problem that I solved this way.

Answer (score 1):

It may help you.

```
<div id="app">
   <v-app id="inspire">
     <v-container>
    <v-row><v-btn @click="add">ADD</v-btn><v-btn 
          @click="remove">REMOVE</v-btn></v-row>
            <v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"  
>
  <template v-slot:body="props">
    <tr v-for="item in props.items">
      <td v-for="(header, index) in headers">
        <span v-if="index">{{ item.cols[index-1] }}</span>
        <span v-else>{{ item.name }}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
 </v-data-table>
      </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/m-imani/pen/wvYzrLG?editors=1010)